# Polymorphic deserialize JSON when type is value of the original JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{name:type, properties...}
```

For example:

```json
{"bulli":"dog","barkVolume":10}
{"dogi":"dog", "barkVolume":7}
{"kitty":"cat", "likesCream":true, "lives":3}
{"milkey":"cat", "likesCream":false, "lives":9}
```

Now, what I want is to deserialize it into a polymorphic object of dog/cat that extends animal. I tried to do something like this, but I know I need to do it a bit different because here my type key is not constant:

```
public class Zoo {
    public Animal animal;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
    })
    public static class Animal {
        public String name;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("dog")
    public static class Dog extends Animal {
        public double barkVolume;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("cat")
    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        boolean likesCream;
        public int lives;
    }
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the `{"bulli":"dog","barkVolume":10}` json object obtaining a `{"barkVolume":10,"type":"dog","name":"bulli"}` new json object that can be deserialized as an `Animal` object. In this case you can convert your json object to a [`ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) and then modify it like below under the condition that the first json property is always *"name": "type"* like in your example:

```
//json is {"bulli":"dog","barkVolume":10}
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(json);
//name contains the "bulli" value
String name = node.fieldNames().next();
//type contains the "dog" value
String type = node.get(name).asText();
//remove the "bulli" property from the json
node.remove(name);
//add the new "type" property from the json with "dog" value
node.put("type", type);
//add the new "name" property from the json with "bulli" value
node.put("name", name);
//ok, deserialization to a Dog value with name "bulli" and barkVolume 10.0
Animal animal = mapper.treeToValue(node, Animal.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing the JSON you provided in a polymorphic way does not seem to be supported. A custom `JsonDeserializer` could give you the results you are looking for. This code does not directly solve your problem, but could be used to derive something useful:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = AnimalDeserializer.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public abstract class Animal {
   public String name;
}

@JsonDeserialize
public class Dog extends Animal {
   @JsonProperty
   public int barkVolume;
}

@JsonDeserialize
public class Cat extends Animal {
   @JsonProperty
   public boolean likesCream;
   @JsonProperty
   public int lives;
}
```

And a deserialization class:

```
public class AnimalDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Animal> {
   @Override
   public Animal deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
      ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
      ObjectNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);

      Iterator<String> fieldIterator = node.fieldNames();
      while (fieldIterator.hasNext()) {
         String fieldName = fieldIterator.next();
         if (node.get(fieldName).asText().equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
            Dog dog = mapper.treeToValue(node, Dog.class);
            dog.name = fieldName;
            return dog;
         } else if (node.get(fieldName).asText().equalsIgnoreCase("cat")) {
            Cat cat = mapper.treeToValue(node, Cat.class);
            cat.name = fieldName;
            return cat;
         }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an animal");
   }
}
```

As you can see some sifting through the node tree is needed and has some problems:

- If another field happens to have the value 'cat' or 'dog' it could trick the deserializer into trying to map it into the wrong class
- Had to set the name manually
- Pain to manage if many derived types are implemented

But if you are working with JSON that is not well formed these are the kinds of hacks required. For reference, this is how I tested it all:

```
public class Farm {

   private static final String json = "[" +
       "{\"bulli\":\"dog\",\"barkVolume\":10},\n" +
       "{\"dogi\":\"dog\", \"barkVolume\":7},\n" +
       "{\"kitty\":\"cat\", \"likesCream\":true, \"lives\":3},\n" +
       "{\"milkey\":\"cat\", \"likesCream\":false, \"lives\":9}" +
       "]";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      List<Animal> animals = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {
      });
      animals.forEach(a -> {
         System.out.println(a.name);
         if (a instanceof Dog) {
            System.out.println(((Dog) a).barkVolume);
         } else if (a instanceof Cat) {
            System.out.println(((Cat) a).lives);
         }
      });
   }
}
```